# Inconsistent dimensions from tf.conv3d with dilations and "VALID" padding

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

When using Tensorflow convolutions with dilations and VALID padding in 1D and 2D the size of the output tensor is smaller than without dilations, as expected. However with 3D convolutions this is not the case and the same shape is outputted regardless of dilations. "REFLECT" padding seems to be used even when "VALID" is requested.

Using Tensorflow 1.8.0.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

data = tf.constant(np.ones((1, 12, 1)))
weights = tf.constant(np.ones((3, 1, 1)))
conv = tf.nn.convolution(data, weights, "VALID")
conv_dil = tf.nn.convolution(data, weights, "VALID", dilation_rate=[2])

data2D = tf.constant(np.ones((1, 12, 12, 1)))
weights2D = tf.constant(np.ones((3, 3, 1, 1)))

conv2D = tf.nn.conv2d(data2D, weights2D, [1, 1, 1, 1], "VALID")
conv_dil2D = tf.nn.conv2d(data2D, weights2D, [1, 1, 1, 1], "VALID", dilations=[1, 2, 2, 1])

data3D = np.ones((1, 12, 12, 12, 1))
data3D[0, 0, 2, 0, 0] = 2
data3D[0, 0, 1, 0, 0] = 2
data3D = tf.constant(data3D)
weights3D = tf.constant(np.ones((3, 3, 3, 1, 1)))


conv3D = tf.nn.conv3d(data3D, weights3D, [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], "VALID")
conv_dil3D = tf.nn.conv3d(data3D, weights3D, [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], "VALID", dilations=[1, 2, 2, 2, 1])


with tf.Session() as sess:
    conv_out, conv_dil_out, conv2D_out, conv_dil2D_out, conv3D_out, conv_dil3D_out = sess.run([conv, conv_dil, conv2D, conv_dil2D, conv3D, conv_dil3D])
    print("1D")
    print(conv_out.shape)
    print(conv_dil_out.shape)
    print("2D")
    print(conv2D_out.shape)
    print(conv_dil2D_out.shape)
    print("3D")
    print(conv3D_out.shape)
    print(conv_dil3D_out.shape)
    print("Values:")
    print(conv_dil3D_out[0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
    print(conv_dil3D_out[0, 0, 0, 2, 0])
    print(conv_dil3D_out[0, 0, 2, 0, 0])
```

Results in:

1D
(1, 10, 1)
(1, 8, 1)
2D
(1, 10, 10, 1)
(1, 8, 8, 1)
3D
(1, 10, 10, 10, 1)
(1, 10, 10, 10, 1)
Values:
29.0
27.0
28.0

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue with version 1.10.0. With CPU, I get "CPU implementation of Conv3D currently only supports dilated rates of 1". With GPU, I first need to change your code, because you are using `tf.float64` (because of NumPy's defaults) and GPU Conv3D kernel is only available for `tf.float16` and `tf.float32`. After changing the types, the resulting shape is correct. Try updating your version of TensorFlow.

Comment: Thanks for attempting to reproduce @jdehesa. I just upgraded to 1.10 and the size is now correct. I had a search before I posted but couldn't find anything but I guess it has been fixed somewhere between 1.8 to 1.10. It also runs 3x as fast.... worth the upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgraded to 1.10 and the problem goes away. The size of the dilated conv3d output is now (1, 8, 8, 8, 1) as expected.